# Detect an object in image using IMAGEMAGICK

Tags: graphics, image-processing, imagemagick

I have an image with Gray Background and 'CUP' in center of it... I want to detect the boundaries of the cup in this image.. After detecting CUP I want to extract the CUP from the image using IMAGEMAGICK.. Note I have many images with different objects (like CUP) in the center and with different background color .. So I am looking for a solution which is applicable to all of them..

Plz comment..

Comment: The question is much clearer, now. Oh, you want answers, too!

Comment: Actually last time in my post description was not clear...

Comment: Also I am using COMMANDLINE TOOLS for IMAGEMAGICK

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use edge-detection algorithms to isolate the shape of your main object: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection

You could also look into the code for the *EdgeImage* effect in ImageMagick, to see how they do it...